# How to handle headers when using cmake for a shared library

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I use cmake to build a cross platform library that most of my projects depends on. The directory structure is as follows:

```
/
--headers
--include
--src
--src_win
--src_linux
```

The header files in the "include" directory basically include other headers from the "headers" directory. So they look for instance like that:

```
#include "../headers/header1.h"
#include "../headers/header2.h"
#include "../headers/header3.h"
```

Now, in order to use this library from other projects, I install the files in the "include" directory and the library. Like that:

```
install(FILES include/mylib1.h DESTINATION include)
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
```

Obviously when in another project I do #include  the subincludes won't find the headers.
How can I correctly handle this? I mean I would have to copy all the files in the "headers" directory to "/usr/local/headers", which isn't really a smart idea. How can I handle this? Is "installing" actually a good idea? Can cmake remember where the library lies (in a git repository clone in my home folder)?
By the way I'm coming from the Windows build world and am used to Visual Studio

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I feel creating "headers" directory is a bad practice at all.

Comment: The point is, that I have different implementations of certain functions depending on the operating system i'm working on. And this is why I want to have the headers separated

Comment: `I have different implementations of certain functions depending on the operating system` - Header files normally contains **declarations**, not *implementations* (*definitions*). In any case, you should **install everything** which can be included by the user, directly or indirectly. `Can cmake remember where the library lies` - Install files are **disconnected** both from source and build ones, and from CMake. This is common practice.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was a bit unclear. I have in a header file some declaration `void someFunc();` and have a different implementation depending on which OS i'm on. This is why I keep the headers separated from the sources (see project directory structure).

So installing appears to be the correct choice. Is this also common practice on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

What Tsycarev is explaining is that your PUBLIC header files should not be OS-dependent. When you create a library, you have to think about what functions and types should be available to the user of your library. We call this subset of functions, types and classes the public API of the library.

If the headers in your `headers` folder should not be part of the public API, the user doesn't need those header files. The correct solution then is to `#include` the files only in your source files, not in the public header files.

If you have functions in your OS-dependent header files that are part of your public API, you should rethink your approach. If you thought about it, but still want to have an OS-dependent public API (there might be reasons for that, for example different string implementations), then you need to ship those header files with the library. But then, your library will also not be platform independent, because your user will have to write a different program depending on the OS.